# Calculate the value of the sum $1+3+5+\cdots+(2n+1)$

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions

I have been thinking about this for a long time, may I know which step of my thinking is wrong as I do not seems to get the correct answer. If I am not going towards the right direction, may I get some help thanks!

My attempt:

Let $S = 1+3+5+\dotsb+(2n+1)\label{a}\tag{1}.$

Then I rearrange S from the last to first terms:

$S = (2n+1)+(2n-1)+(2n-3)+\dotsb+1\label{b}\tag{2}.$

Adding the two series $(1)+(2)$:

$$2S = (2n+2)+(2n+2)+(2n+2)+\dotsb+(2n+2),$$

I have $n$ copies of $(2n+2)$.

Therefore:

$2S = n(2n+2)$

$S = n(n+1)$.

Comment: What's the right answer:) ?

Comment: The answer is (n+1)^2

Comment: Only if the first number is indexed at $0$, rather than $1$.  Try $n = 2$: If your series is $1+3$, you end up with $4 = 2^2$, not $3^2$.

Comment: Everything is correct except for one thing. You have $n+1$ numbers in your list $1,… 2n+1$, not $n$ of them. So $2S=(n+1)(2n+2)$.

Comment: @MartinKochanski May I ask you how do I get n + 1. I am not getting it.

Comment: The easiest way to see it is to put $n=1$. Then $2n+1=3$, and your sum is $1+3$, which has two terms. Thus $n=1$ gives two terms, not one.

Comment: @MartinKochanski I need some clarifications, does it mean that 1 is the first term, and the number after 1 e.g(3+5+⋯+(2n+1)1+3+5+⋯+(2n+1)) is the second term?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Build a square in the following manner. On your first step, place $1$ block. On your second step put $3$ blocks around that, and on your third step put $5$ blocks around what you have, and so on. I think it should be pretty easy to see that the sum of the blocks is the area of the square for the step you are on.

In other words, the sum of the first $n$ odd integers is

$$
(2(1) - 1) + (2(2) - 1) + \dotsb + (2(n) - 1) = n^2.
$$

Image source: google "sum of first $n$ odd numbers."

Answer (score 2):

The last of $n$ numbers starting from $1, 3, 5, \ldots$ is $2n-1$, not $2n+1$.  Replace accordingly and you should obtain the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$S=1+3+5+7+\cdots 2r+1$$
$$S=2r+1 +2r-1+2r-3+2r-5+2r-7 +\cdots 1  $$
$$2S=2(2r+1)+r(2r)$$
$$S=r^2+2r+1=(r+1)^2$$
Instead of $r^{th}$ term  you have written $(r+1)^{th}$ term.

This can also be verified using 
$$a_r=a + (n-1)d$$
$$a_r=2r-1 \qquad a_{r+1}=2r +1 $$
You can do it easily by this

We got genral term as $(2r-1)$
$$\sum_{r=1}^n2r-1$$
$$2\sum_{r=1}^n r-\sum_{r=1}^n1$$

Answer (score 0):

Only have $n-1$ numbers of (2n+2)

therefore:

2S = (n-1)(2n+2)

S = (n-1)(n+1)

Reason:

when $n=1$, then first term is 3 rather than 1.
Therefore, you only have $n-1$ numbers of (2n+2).

Comment: If you do a couple of examples, you'll see that $S$ is always a perfect square, not one less than a square, which is what the formula $S=(n-1)(n+1)=n^2-1$ gives.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, the sequence 1,3,5,........(2n+1) is arithmetic sequence
having first term let say f = 1, last term say l = (2n+1) and common difference d = 2 , {(3-1),(5-3)......so on}  and the sequence have n+1 terms so it can be represented as 1,3,5,..........(2n-1),(2(n+1)-1)

we can use formula for sum of arithmetic sequence having first term(f), last term(l) and total number of terms(n) as:

sum = n(f+l)/2

so,
 sum = (n+1)(1+2n+1)/2

```
      = (n+1)(n+1)
      = (n+1)^2
```

Hope it helps.......

Comment: maths is hard to read if not formatted well, So please learn the basics here,  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

$$1+3+5+\cdots+(2n+1) = \sum_{k=0}^n (2 k + 1) = 2 \binom{n+1}{2} + (n+1) = (n+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum^n_{k=1} (2n-1) \implies \sum^n_{k=1} 2n- \sum^n_{k=1} 1 \implies {2(n)(n+1)\over2} - n \implies n^2+n-n\implies n^2$$